# How to Clone Array To Another Array in Mongo Shell

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-shell

I have some query to accomplish with some array.

### In MongoDB Shell

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4];
var array2 = [];

array2 = array1.Clone();
```

There is no Clone() function in mongodb shell. How can i clone it to another array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `array.slice(0)`, this will clone your array number. Another way of cloning using `[spread][1]` operator ES6.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3]
var cloned = arr.splice(0)

var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var cloned2 = [...arr2]

console.log('cloned:', cloned)
console.log('cloned 2:', cloned2)
```